# Does a Web Developer need a Reseller account?

Tags: reseller

I have a shared hosting account at Hostgator. I am about to advertise my web services and expect to build a few websites for customers soon. It just occurred to me that perhaps I should be upgrading to Reseller Accounts to give each client their own c-panel.

I can always create unlimited email accounts for them. Is this best practices or is ther a better solution.

Is there any reason I should use Reseller rather then Shared Hosting? My sites run fast at the moment.

Comment: Admin, please delete question. I have found out that it is illegal not to have one and to host other sites.

Comment: It's not illegal. It's just potentially against some web hosts' ToS.

Comment: Also, leaving your question undeleted will help others with the same question you had, as is the goal of Stack Exchange :)

Answer (score 4):

**Reseller Web Hosting - The small print**

You should be aware that a lot of resellers accounts are not the same as if you was to buy just a single account from them. Some companies restrict or allocate the amount of resources you can have so each customer you add the slower your service becomes. This isn't always the case but some do it, furthermore you might find that your reseller account is put on a server with many other resellers meaning you're sharing reseller resources which ultimately will be slower than the other service... Again this is something you have to ask. Some companies offer lower contention on their reseller accounts (i.e. "Low Density" hosting) and this costs much more but can be worth while taking.

**You're a Website Designer not a Webmaster/Web Administrator**

Another thing to consider is do you want to spend time resolving hosting issues? If you give them accounts they will come to you for support, if I was in your shoes I'd charge monthly managed costs to them if they expect support for their hosting.

**Personal Experience**

Personally I opt to use VPS with webmin and virtualmin. For each 5 customers or so I increase the resources - this is by far the most responsive and best service you can provide without buying a dedicated server. You should of be aware of the upkeep involved and forward these costs monthly to your customers. If a customer isn't willing to pay enough to have you manage just get them to buy a shared account and let them have the responsibility of maintaining it. Remember time is money and try to get some back for hosting/managing.

Managed servers/hosting costs a lot of money from web hosts don't just give them cheap hosting because your making the site for them...

Comment: And can you create private c-panels for clients with VPS? And what would you do when you reach the maximum disk space?

Comment: Yes you can use cpanel for with an VPS just find a good VPS provider and ask them how much for the license. I use Directadmin as its cheaper but cpanel is better, but more costly.

Comment: Thanks, and I suppose having a managed VPS (I know no Linux at all) isnt harder then managing a Shared?

Comment: @LuckyLuke Usually with a reseller account on a shared host you'll have a CPanel web access to add sites to your account, while with a VPS you'll have more direct access to the virtual OS.